# Salvar formula postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Tenho a seguinte query

```
UPDATE teste SET
    equacao = 'X*254/1024+15.2', 
    zerar = False, 
    MinValid = 0.00 
WHERE id = 1 
RETURNING *
```

Ela executa normalmente, mas quando vou chegar no banco de dados o sinal de mais `+` desaparece: `X*254/1024 15.2`.

Como eu devo modificar a query para que o sinal de mais seja salvo como um caracterer?

Comment: Porque -1? Algum ponto não ficou claro minha duvida? Ou devo editar alguma coisa?

Comment: Qual o tipo do campo `equacao`?

Comment: o tipo é `character varying`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7433201/540552

Comment: Eu não desejo que o banco de dados resolva a formula, só quero que ele salve ela como um texto qualquer. Como outra string qualquer.

Comment: Muito estranho o `+` desaparecer. Como é que você está realizando a conexão no banco de dados e em qual ambiente você está executando isso?

Answer (score 1):

O problema não era no pgAdmin como tinha dito, e sim na pagina php que recebia o POST e realizava a inserção. O `+` é convertido para `<espaço>`, para utilizar o caractere `+` é preciso trocar ele por `%2B` no parâmetro a ser passado.